# Is there any way we can run fragment shader on non-graphics-card pc?

Tags: opengl, glsl, opencl

Is there any way we can run fragment shader on non-graphics-card pc? 
I don't have graphics card on my machine, I have intel OpenCL sdk, and visual studio 2010 installed.

Answer (score 2):

When programming with OpenCL, you do not write fragment shaders.  You write *kernels* in the OpenCL C programming language.  And yes, using the Intel OpenCL SDK, you can run such kernels on your CPU compute device.

Comment: What is the difference between them, I'm new to openCL,

Comment: There is some level of integration between OpenCL and OpenGL/DirectX, but strictly speaking, a "pixel shader" or "fragment shader" is written in a shading language and controlled using OpenGL or DirectX. See Appendix C of AMD's guide for the distinction between an OpenCL kernel and a shader: http://developer.amd.com/sdks/amdappsdk/assets/AMD_Accelerated_Parallel_Processing_OpenCL_Programming_Guide.pdf

Comment: You might want to have a look at OpenCL Image memory objects, and the various language builtins OpenCL C provides for operating on them.  If you are interested in pure pixel-processing, they are the closest analogue to fragment shaders you will find in OpenCL.

Comment: I'm interested in coloring each pixel indivisually. http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/loading.php I have tried running this OPENGLES GLSL fragment shader on my machine it worked.. But I don't know how to manipulate color of each pixel here .. and whether complex fragment shaders are supported by GLSL without graphics card

Comment: Yes - then you can certainly experiment on the CPU with image memory objects.  A quick google for `OpenCL image processing example` turned up [this](http://royger.org/opencl/?cat=10).

Comment: Actually I'm a little bit familier with openGL, so I thought if the work can be done with glsl , on my machine without graphics card... then it wud be better.. 
as i have to finish implementing some part of this paper .. 
refer ppt to get idea 
http://www.cemyuksel.com/research/meshcolors/meshcolors_SIGGRAPH2010.pdf
 in comin 2 3 days ..
A code plotting the mesh, which has access to each of the mesh vertices wud be helpfull 
Now I was going thru orange buk for GLSL
Please help, if I'm headin to wrong direction, and per pixel coloring can't be done in glsl using fragment shader..